# Is it better to store a list of objects, or a list of dicts representing objects in class attribute with python?

Tags: python, dictionary, object

Say I'm going to iterate over the list frequently. Assuming I'm getting the data as a list of dicts to begin with. Is there a performance reason to use one over the other?

Example

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
```

Option 1 stores a list of dicts and yields a dict representing a car-

```
class DealershipLot:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.cars_on_lot = data

    __iter__(self):
        for car in self.cars_on_lot:
            yield car
```

Option 2 stores a list of car objects and yields a car object-

```
class DealershipLot:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.cars_on_lot = []
        for car in data:
            self.cars_on_lot.append(Car(car))

    def __iter__(self):
        for car in self.cars_on_lot:
            yield car
```

Option 3 stores a list of dicts and yields a car object-

```
class DealershipLot:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.cars_on_lot = data

    def __iter__(self):
        for car in self.cars_on_lot:
            yield Car(car)
```

Comment: I believe this may be subjective, but it depends on the use case.  If you arent using any functionality leveraged by classes, then it really is just a storage mechanism.  If it is a storage mechanism, it should be as small a payload as possible. While a class can represent properties, usually there is additional needs, functionality for example which is written into the implementation.  So, it comes down to "It Depends".

Comment: > If it is a storage mechanism, it should be as small a payload as possible.
@Fallenreaper Would that be storing a list of dicts in this case, not objects?

Comment: Do you mean `Car(**car)`?

Comment: Are you using these `Car` objects as POD structs or do they have additional properties?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Possibly. I didn't know if I would need to use that in this case.

Comment: Use the timeit module and test your options. Leave it as an answer here. I'm curious.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I don't know what POD structs mean, but all attributes would be included in the original data. The `Car` objects would have methods such as `wash`, and `detail`.

Comment: @kysevenle: *"Is there a performance reason to use one over the other?"*: You want to use *"methods such as `wash`, and `detail`"* then create the `Car object` **once**.

Comment: @kysevenle dicts have their own functionality built into their datastructure as well.  If you want it as small as possible, Json would be the ideal.  It would abstract the overhead of dict utility functions as well.

Comment: @kysevenle Ultimately, I would say that it really depends on the operations you want to accomplish with that data.  A Dict is pretty good option, as it does have most utilities in place you would likely need.